# Vuelidate not validating the zip file type added from Windows only

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vuelidate

I have added Vuelidate to validate the forms in Vue Component. Here is the code for the validation part in markup:

```
 <input name="attachment"
                               v-validate="'mimes:image/*,pdf,doc,docx,xls,xlsx,pdf,zip|size:100000'"
                               type="file"
                               @change="onAttachmentChange"/>
```

This works well whenever .zip file is added from the devices other than with Windows OS. But when I upload the .zip file from Windows OS, it displays validation error for the file is not of valid file type. The validation also works correctly for other criteria but the validation is only not working for .zip file type uploaded from Windows OS.

Here are related codes for this validation part:

```
export default {
    name: 'CreateNewsComponent',
    data() {
        return {
            createNews: false,
            title: "",
            description: "",
            image: "",
            video: "",
            video_thumbnails: "",
            attachment: "",
            uploading: {
                'image': false,
                'video': false,
                'video_thumbnails': false,
                'attachment': false
            },
        }
    },
    methods: {
        postNews() {
            this.$validator.validate().then(result => {
                if (result) {
                    this.errors.clear();

                    this.$store.commit('employer/toggleLoader', true);

                    let _current = this;
                    axios.post('/news', {
                        title: this.title,
                        description: this.description,
                        image: this.image,
                        video: this.video,
                        video_thumbnails: this.video_thumbnails,
                        attachment: this.attachment,
                        user_id: "OAM",

                    })
                    .then(function (response) {
                        if (response.data.sucess === false) {
                            _current.showNotification('error', response.data.message);
                        } else {
                            _current.$bus.$emit('__OMA__refreshNews');
                            _current.showNotification('success', 'Successfully created news.');
                            _current.resetForm();
                        }
                        _current.$store.commit('employer/toggleLoader', false);

                    })
                    .catch(function (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                        _current.errors = error.message;
                        _current.showNotification('error', err.message);
                        _current.$store.commit('employer/toggleLoader', false);
                    });
                }
            });
        },
        toggleNewsCreateFrom(e) {
            this.resetForm();
            this.createNews = !this.createNews;
        },
        onImageChange(e) {
            this.uploading.image = true;
            let files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
            if (!files.length) {
                return;
            }
            this.createImage(files[0]);
        },
        onVideoThumbnailChange(e) {
            this.uploading.video_thumbnails = true;
            let files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
            if (!files.length) {
                return;
            }
            this.createVideoThumbnail(files[0]);
        },
        createImage(file) {
            let image = new Image();
            let reader = new FileReader();
            let vm = this;

            reader.onload = (e) => {
                vm.image = e.target.result;
                vm.uploadFile(file, 'image');
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        },
        createVideoThumbnail(file) {
            let reader = new FileReader();
            let vm = this;

            reader.onload = (e) => {
                vm.video_thumbnails = e.target.result;
                vm.uploadFile(file, 'video_thumbnails');
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        },
        onVideoChange(event) {
            this.uploading.video = true;
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

                if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length > 0) {
                    this.uploadFile(event.target.files[0], 'video');
                    resolve();
                } else {
                    console.log("Error!! uploading video");
                    reject();
                }
            });
        },
        onAttachmentChange(event) {
            this.uploading.attachment = true;
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length > 0) {
                    this.uploading.attachment = true;
                    this.uploadFile(event.target.files[0], 'attachment');
                    resolve();
                } else {
                    console.log("Error!! uploading attachment");
                    reject();
                }
            });
        },
        removeFile: function (fileType) {
            this[fileType] = '';
        },
        resetForm() {
            this.createNews = false;
            this.title = "";
            this.description = "";
            this.image = "";
            this.video = "";
            this.video_thumbnails = "";
            this.attachment = "";
            this.errors.clear();
            this.uploading.image = false;
            this.uploading.video = false;
            this.uploading.video_thumbnails = false;
            this.uploading.attachment = false;
        },
        showNotification(type, message) {
            this.$notify({
                group: 'employer',
                title: 'Important message',
                text: message,
                type: type,
            });
        },
        uploadFile(file, type) {
            this.uploading[type] = true;
            let vm = this;

            let formData = new FormData();
            formData.append(type, file);

            axios.post('/news/file/upload', formData, {headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}})
                .then((response) => {
                    if (response.data.success === false) {
                        vm.showNotification('error', response.data.message);
                        vm[type] = '';
                        vm.uploading[type] = false;
                        return;
                    }
                    vm[type] = response.data.url;
                    vm.uploading[type] = false;
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.warn(err);
                    vm.showNotification('error', err.message);
                    vm[type] = '';
                    vm.uploading[type] = false;
                });
        }
    }
}
```